# QTextDocument, QPdfWriter - how to scale output

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt5

I have createated a `QTextDocument` with a table in it. Now I'm trying to render it into PDF format using `QPdfWriter` (Qt 5.2.1). This is how I do it:

```
QPdfWriter pdfWriter(output);
QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);
doc->drawContents(&painter);
```

It works, but the problem is that the table in PDF is really, really tiny. What can I do to scale it up? I mean to scale up the whole document, not just this table, because I plan to add more contents to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `QPainter::scale()`, so in my case:

```
QPdfWriter pdfWriter(output);
QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);
painter.scale(20.0, 20.0);
doc->drawContents(&painter);
```

This causes painter to paint everything 20 times bigger.

I still don't know why `QPdfWriter` paints everything so tiny, but the problem can be solved as above.

Answer (score 2):

With current Qt (>= 5.3) you just need to call: `QPdfWriter::setResolution(int dpi)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QPdfWriter::setPageSizeMM()` or `QPdfWriter::setPageSize()` to set size of a page. To test this idea you can just add `pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A0);` in your code.

Comment: But this doesn't scale up the rendered table. It just cuts the page to desired size. What if then I wanted to print it on A4? I mean, I can set page size to 3cm x 3cm and my table looks fine then, but I cannot print on 3x3cm paper.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been caught out by this too. I figured out what was going on when I called the `widthMM()` and `width()` functions of `QPdfWriter`.  The widthMM was about 200 which is right for an A4/Letter page (a sensible default), but the `width` was returned as about 9600.  I called `logicalDpiX()` and that returned 1200.

So what this indicates is that the logical unit of the `QPdfWriter` is the 'dot', where there are by default 1200 dots per inch.  You therefore need to scale between your own logical units and 'dots'.  For instance if your logical unit is a Point then you need to do something like this:

```
QPdfWriter writer(filename);
int logicalDPIX=writer.logicalDpiX();
const int PointsPerInch=72;

QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&writer)
QTransform t;
float scaling=(float)logicalDPIX/PointsPerInch;  // 16.6
t.scale(scaling,scaling);

// do drawing with painter
painter.end()
painter.setTransform(t);
```